# testing method which create a new thread and result we get from event ( NUnit 2.6 )

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have class which have one public method `Start`, one private method and one event `Finishing`. `Start` call `new Thread( private_method )`. Private method return value using event. When this method finish their work, then call this event.

Now I want to write test to this class. If I write it like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass();

        someObject.Finishing += new SomeClass.FinishingEventHandler((sender, a) =>
        {
            Assert.True(false);
        });
        someObject.Start(); // when this method will finish, then call event Finishing
    }
```

It should be fail, but it isn't. I think that method `Test1` is finished before event is raised. So, how can I test this code? How test method, which create a new thread, and result we get from event

Answer (score 18, accepted):

NUnit has built-in feature for waiting for assertion. It is called 'After':

```
[Test]
public void ShouldRaiseFinishedEvent()
{
    SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass();
    bool eventRaised = false;
    someObject.SomethingFinished += (o, e) => { eventRaised = true; };

    someObject.DoSomething();
    Assert.That(eventRaised, Is.True.After(500));
}
```

Comment: Didn't know that, I use FluentAssertions instead of the built in NUnit assertions. Just checked it out and they have some Event Monitoring assertions. http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: Built-in waiting pretty good. It allows to define timeout and polling interval Is.EqualTo("Done").After(500, 50). So you don't need to wait long if something happens quickly :)

Comment: This solution look very nice, but.. I have problem with this. I'm not sure what is happend. In my case `eventRaised` was correctly set to `true` (I write it on console). But ` Assert.That(eventRaised, Is.True.After(5000));' "told me" that `eventRaised` is `false`.. How is it possible? I'm not sure, but maybe it is problem with `bool`, it is not refereced class, so maybe `Assert.That()` get this `eventRaised` like false, and it isn't reference to `eventRaised` which I set to `true` in `event`..

Comment: Well, it definitely should work with boolean. Do you need help on eventRaised updating?

Comment: Btw there is some tricky moment - when you waiting for something to change state async, NUnit will evaluate value only during first verification. So, here is trick: Assert.That(delegate { return x.Bar; }, Is.True.After(500, 50)); That makes NUnit evaluate property value each time.

Answer (score 2):

```
[Test]
public void ShouldRaiseFinishedEvent()
{
    SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass();
    AutoResetEvent eventRaised = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    someObject.SomethingFinished += (o, e) => { eventRaised.Set(); };

    someObject.DoSomething();
    Assert.IsTrue(eventRaised.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)));
}
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

First of all, NUnit and its various hosting environments had, or still have, various defects and limitations around threads started from within a test.  In particular, if you do not make sure that the thread completes before the test execution is finished, then NUnit has no idea that someone is executing in code that it is going to unload after the test has returned.  I remember this pattern regularly causing crashes of VS when NUnit was being executed from it via Resharper integration, as well as occasional glitches and memory leaks of the GUI and console runners provided with NUnit.

That said, you need to ensure two things.

1. Elementary safety of the test environment by joining all the threads that you spawn.
2. Throwing all exceptions that indicate test failure on the main thread only.  This means that the background thread has to communicate its results to the main thread, and that one has to `Assert` all the various invariants.

Even better, structure your code so that you can unit test it without background threads - if possible.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I thought that my teacher told me use NUnit because is very good framework.. I was wrong;)

Comment: @nirmus - No, NUnit is absolutely great!  But the idea behind *unit* testing is that you ideally test very small chunks of code (units).  Big integration testing is possible as well, but it must be self contained.  If you make something moving, you should also stop it inside the test so that it is self contained.  NUnit does not know what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you can unit test multi threaded components but it is not clean like regular unit tests. I have mostly encountered it in Acceptance Tests and have had great success with the .net 4 [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) and [Parallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx) classes. However in this case a simple sleep might get you going but if you start doing lots of these tests you might want a more performant way of doing it.

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    bool wasCalled = false;

    SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass();

    someObject.Finishing += new SomeClass.FinishingEventHandler((sender, a) =>
    {
        wasCalled = true;
    });
    someObject.Start(); // when this method will finish, then call event Finishing

    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    Assert.True(wasCalled);
}
```

What ever you do you need some timeout somewhere that will cause the test to finish instead of hanging forever, this could be done in the test itself or some test libraries have a [Timeout](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=timeout&r=2.5) attribute you can decorate the test with.